# Update database values only for values edited by a submitted form

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli

I currently have a database with clients info on it.
I also have a page for every client that display every single info from the database into some fields of a form, and in the same page there's an update button. 
In this way I want to update in the database only the fields that has been changed in the form. 
Which is the best approach?
Or I simply need to update every single columns, considered that mysql update function recognizes and updates only the values that has been changed?

Comment: Check what fields were changed. Run an update function for those fields only. Make sure to use prepared functions... Did you eve try anything?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to build object's in PHP for each database object (CustomerInformation) for instance... Then you could do this:

```
include 'db.customerinformation.php'; /* you'll need to create this file, and populate it with code to do the following */

$cust = new CustomerInformation;
$cust->Open($_POST['DatabaseID']);
$cust->_CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName'];
$cust->_Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$cust->_Email = $_POST['Email'];
$cust->Update();
```

And that's it! This is a simplification obviously of what you need to do, but absolutely the correct way.

Example of db.customerinformation.php

```
class CustomerInformation {

      public $_DatabaseID = '';
      public $_CompanyName = '';


      function Open($id) {
               // MySQL code to open the DB object ... you need to code this.
               $this->_CompanyName = $row['CompanyName']; /*database field for company name */
      }


      function Update() {
            // Make code to update the entire row based on $_DatabaseID
      }
```

}